# RedirectStandardOutput and the pause command in batch files

Tags: c#, .net, redirectstandardoutput

In my C# code, I have to run some external processes. These could be batch files or executables. I redirect the output to a window of my own by having `RedirectStandardOutput` of the `ProcessStartInfo` be true. This allows the user to review the output even after the external process has finished. I also redirect the input so the user can press keys if necessary. This works very well in general.

However, I have one problem. Some of the batch files use the `PAUSE` command. Apparently the output isn't flushed by the command until a key has been pressed. Thus, the user never sees the prompt. So only after a key has been pressed will the user see that he should have pressed a key to continue. Is there a way to make this work (besides "Don't use PAUSE")?

EDIT: The batch files run the user's CAM post-processor and are usually created by the user (or the user's IT department). So requiring changes to these files or "hacking" by creating a pause.exe aren't really viable solutions (unless as very last resort).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CMD, Try

```
batchWithPause.bat < nul
```

In C# that would be something like:

```
 Process.Start("batchWithPause.bat", "< nul");
```

**EDIT** So you simply want to the user to see "Press any key to continue"? 
Then add

```
@echo "Press any key to continue..."
```

before each `pause` call. You could also:

1. Write your own pause.bat that does that essentially
2. Write a simple pause.exe, say in c#:

   public static void Pause() 
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to continue.");
     Console.Read();
   }

**EDIT 2** I understand your problem now. Both the async OutputDataReceived and StreamReader.ReadLine() would read pause's "Press any key to continue" only after the user has pressed a key. However, if you were to loop StreamReader.Read() yourself, you would also get the "Press any key to continue". So this appears to be your only possible route.

Comment: This redirects the input, so the pause command is skipped. But I want the pause command to work (and it does). The problem is that the text isn't written to the output, so the user does not know to press a key to continue.

Comment: @Daniel See my edit. Don't know why the markup is wrong in the pause() implementation

Comment: Unfortunately the batch files are supplied by the user (they run the CAM post-processor). Replacing the pause command (or telling them "Don't use pause") are two possible solution, but neither "solution" is really what I would want to do.

Comment: With those hints I got it working. However, two caveats: 1) `Read()` blocks if there is no char "waiting" in the output. So I run this on a separate thread. 2) Once we are done and no more characters are left, `EndOfStream` is true. Trying to read will result in an exception. However, checking this property also blocks if there is no char waiting on the output(as above).

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you could use ReadBlock? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readblock.aspx

Comment: Also, what you're saying is weird - Read is supposed to return -1 when it reaches the end of the stream.. perhaps you forgot to check for it ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8.aspx