# C# - Batch file output not displaying "Press any key to continue..." until after I press a key

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-file, console

As the title says I have a batch file that uses a pause.
This is an example batch file the I'll use to explain the issue:

```
@echo off
pause
echo DONE
pause
```

When running the batch file from the explorer it displays the following:

```
"Press any key to continue..."
```

[image: cmd0]

And then When the user presses a key the following is displayed:

```
Press any key to continue...
DONE
Press any key to continue...
```

[image: cmd1]

The problem I'm having is that when running this .bat file from my windows forms application the output doesn't display "Press any key to continue..." until after the user has pressed a key.
This is a problem as the user needs to know that they need to press a key before they press it.
Here is a [Video](https://youtu.be/JQQaeEK9Bw4) displaying the issue.

When the batch file exectutes the circles on the left turn grey. The mouse then moves to the textbox and I press a key on the keyboard. Then the output textbox shows the text.

So Im experiementing and I add a line to the .bat file:

```
@echo off
echo Why is this line showing but the other line doesn't until i press a key?
pause
echo DONE
pause
```

Here is the [result](https://youtu.be/pzOESMfyQ64).

So here is the code:

```
void StartNewProcess(string batchFile)
    {
        //Focuses the input textbox
        Input_TextBox.Focus();
        //Set up process
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(batchFile);
        processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = appDir;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process = new Process();
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        //Start process
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        //This is the input textbox
        stdin = process.StandardInput;

        process.OutputDataReceived += (s, evt) =>
        {
            if (evt.Data != null)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {

                    newOutputLine = evt.Data; //Reference to current incoming line of text
                    Output_TextBox.AppendText(newOutputLine + Environment.NewLine);
                    Output_TextBox.ScrollToCaret();
                    if (evt.Data == "DONE")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Task completed successfully!", "Notification");
                        Output_TextBox.Text = ""; //Clear the output textbox
                    }
                }));
            }
        };
        
        process.Exited += (s, evt) => {
            process.Close();
            if (process != null)
            {
                process.Dispose();
            }
        };
    }

    private void Input_Panel_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            stdin.WriteLine(Input_TextBox.Text);
        }
    }
```

What in the world do I need to do to get "Press any key to continue..." to display before the key is pressed?

This isn't the only instance of this problem I've faced. If for example the batch file requires a value to be inputted as a response to a choice, the question doesn't display until the answer has been inputted... e.g. "enter your name: " won't display until after the user has inputted the name and pressed return at which point it will display "enter your name: Sample Name".
Which is not helpful to the user because they need to know that they need to enter a name before they enter it.

I have many batch files which display alot of choices and the user is required to know what those choices are in order for my application to work. So this functionality is like the main bit. xD

Any ideas?

Thanks

****EDIT****
So thanks to @MatthewMiller for providing me with a solution. And so here it is for everyone else:

```
void StartNewProcess(string batchFile)
    {
        //Set up process
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new   ProcessStartInfo(batchFile);
        processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = appDir;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process = new Process();
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        //Start process
        process.Start();
        //process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        //This is the input textbox
        stdin = process.StandardInput;

        // Get the output stream from the new process.
        StreamReader stdout = process.StandardOutput;

        // Define a buffer we will use to store characters read.
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1;
        char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];

        // The following specifies reading from the output stream to a buffer
        // and then appending the result to the form.
        Task<int> readTask = stdout.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        Action<Task<int>> appendAction = null;

        appendAction = (read) => {
            string bufferString = new string(buffer);
            // `read.Result` represents the number of characters read.
            string newText = bufferString.Substring(0, read.Result);
            // *Append new text to form here.* NOTE: New text might not be a complete line.
            SetText(newText); //Have to set text this way due to other      thread
            // If we read in an entire buffer of text, we need to keep     reading.
            // Otherwise, stop reading and finish up.
            if (read.Result == BUFFER_SIZE)
            {
                readTask = stdout.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                readTask.ContinueWith(appendAction);
            }
            else
            {
                // *Handle process has ended here.*
            }
        };
        readTask.ContinueWith(appendAction);
}

private void SetText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.Output_TextBox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            Output_TextBox.AppendText(text);
        }
    }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: It seems to me like the `"Press any key to continue..."` isn't being flushed by the `pause` command. That is, it isn't going to call `OutputDataReceived` until another command properly flushes the stream. See this question, it may answer yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995151/redirectstandardoutput-and-the-pause-command-in-batch-files

Comment: If Matthew is right (and I think he is) instead of `pause` use `echo Press any key...` and `pause >nul`. Same with `set /p "var=Prompt:" as `echo Prompt:` and `set /p var=`. Suspected reason: both `pause` and `set /p` don't write a `CRLF` before you press `ENTER` and C# captures the line, when it's finished (with a `CRLF`)

Comment: @Stephan Hi I'm trying to go through the link that Matthew provided at the moment. In this case though I am unable to change the bat files as they are provided by an external source. The application in my case is just a gui to run the batch files, give answers and also return the output.

Thanks

Comment: In batch, you can hide input using `> nul` like @Stephan demonstrated in his comment. If you want the prompt to quarentee parse before the pause itself, use Stephan's suggestion, `echo Prompt for input && pause >nul`

Comment: @NekoMusume Hi, in my case this is not possible, The bat files will be uneditted as they are provided externally and are updated on a regualr basis. My application is just a gui to launch batch files and allows the user to input repsonses.

Editting the bat files are not an option in my case.

Thanks

Comment: If you start your batch file with `cmd.exe` with arguments, e.g.,  `/K START /B /WAIT yourbatchfile.cmd` and you send `stdin.Write((char)13);` right after you start your Process, the first `Press any key to continue...` will be shown, waiting for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Instead of using the `process.OutputDataReceived` event, use the standard output stream from the process.

```cs
// Get the output stream from the new process.
StreamReader stdout = process.StandardOutput;

// Define a buffer we will use to store characters read.
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1;
char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];

// The following specifies reading from the output stream to a buffer
// and then appending the result to the form.
Task<int> readTask = stdout.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
Action<Task<int>> appendAction = null;

appendAction = (read) => {
  string bufferString = new string(buffer);
  // `read.Result` represents the number of characters read.
  string newText = bufferString.Substring(0, read.Result); 
  // *Append new text to form here.* NOTE: New text might not be a complete line.

  // If we read in an entire buffer of text, we need to keep reading.
  // Otherwise, stop reading and finish up.
  if (read.Result == BUFFER_SIZE)
  {
    readTask = stdout.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    readTask.ContinueWith(appendAction);
  }
  else
  {
    // *Handle process has ended here.*
  }
};
readTask.ContinueWith(appendAction);
```

This essentially does the same thing as your original code. However, this time, we use the standard output stream to read characters one by one. This code does it asynchronously as to not block your GUI. Let me know if it works or if you have any questions. I can't test it out because I'm not running Windows.

See this post on taking a certain action after a task completes that I used in this solution: [How to get notification that a System.Threading.Tasks.Task has completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462104/how-to-get-notification-that-a-system-threading-tasks-task-has-completed)

*Edit*:

There was a mistake in my first answer because of not predefining `appendAction` and the substring `bufferString.Substring(read.Result)` should have been `bufferString.Substring(0, read.Result)`. These errors have been fixed. Here is a Fiddle demonstrating a working example using a `StringReader`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LinVWc

Comment: Hi, So I've given your code a try, I did get an error here:
if (!stdout.EndOfStream)
                {
                    readTask = stdout.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                    //readTask.ContinueWith(appendAction); //commented out as it stated that the var was unnassigned.
                }

Just to test I have tried the following but nothing is returned in the console:
// *Append new text to form here.* NOTE: New text might not be a complete line.
                Console.WriteLine(newText);

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: @SmellyFox, you are absolutely correct in your idea. I made a few mistakes in my code. We need to predefine `readTask` to avoid the error you pointed out. Also, `bufferString.Substring(read.Result)` should be `bufferString.Substring(0, read.Result)` because the first one will always produce an empty string. I've modified my code in my answer and provided a Fiddle to a sample implementation.